# cocoa properly copy file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, error-handling, copy, nsfilemanager

I want to implement a simple file save, currently I am using 
`writeToUrl :options :error` method of `NSData`, it does the job, but I want to know what is the proper way to do so ?

I mean if file with the same name is already exists and I need to ask user for additional input, failed to copy and things like that.

Is there something built in cocoa framework that takes care of that ?
I took a look at `NSFileManager` but I can't see things like that there ?

I am sorry if this question is very noobish , but I never touched file system except user defaults before, and can't find desired methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to write your own error handling code. Checking if the file already exists, telling the user, prompting for a new name. All these things are developer code.

Comment: Sad, I someway believed that Apple wrapped it, then can I ask a mini question? I also couldn't find the `sheet` that asks "overwrite , keep both , cancel" is there such sheet ? or I should do it myself as well ?

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Yes, you need to do that as well. Consider all the various ways the multitudes of developers and their multitudes of UI could possibile want this to work and look like. There is really not a general solution that would cover a large percentage of usages.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought it is something common indeed like `NSopenPanel` 
but if no then not... will take a couple more hours to get it to work ... thanks for fast answer and saving me a lot of search time (because I would continue to look for something like this for maybe couple of days Laziness at it best u know :) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you use NSSavePanel to ask the user for a path where to save the file, it will take care of displaying a sheet when the path already exists.

You can then use NSAlert to display any errors that may happen during the saving process.

Comment: Thanks for info, however in my particular situation, I need to pick a DIRECTORY path from the user and then throw there about 4-5 files...

So Sadly it won't help me